# Grouping data on a daily cumulative timeseries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big table with sales data. Every row contains several sales information, but for our discussion, it contains a datetime column and a sale value.

I´ve been trying to group the sales by a 5min freq time series using grouper.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : [datetime.datetime(2022,11,1,0,10,0), datetime.datetime(2022,11,1,0,25,0),datetime.datetime(2022,11,1,0,35,0)],
    'gmv' : [10,20,40]})
df = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='5Min', origin='start_day', convention = 'start', dropna = False, sort=True, closed = 'left')]).aggregate({'gmv' :'sum'}).reset_index()
df["cum_sale"]=df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date])['gmv'].cumsum(axis=0)
```

But despite I´ve required a 5min freq, the first result is a 10min delay. I know the first 5min does not have any transaction, but how can a "force" it to exist?

[image]

Is there a better way to organize such data? After turning it on a daily cumulative sales, I am plotting it, but the "10 min" offset above is breaking my graph.

---

**Update for futher questions**

This is my origin table value_counts()

[image]

I am trying to apply the suggested answer

```
tdf = teste[['data', 'marca','gmv']]
tdf = tdf.astype({'marca':'str'}) #("marca" was a category type)
dti = pd.date_range(tdf['data'].min().normalize(), tdf['data'].max(), freq='5min', name='data')
df = tdf.set_index('data').reindex(dti, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df['cum_sale'] = df.resample('D', on='data')['gmv'].cumsum()
df
```

but now my table is almost empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas use the `start_date` as `origin` to compute groups and interpolate from first to last values but it doesn't extrapolate missing dates outside of its range. You have to handle it manually::

```
dti = pd.date_range(data['date'].min().normalize(), data['date'].max(), freq='5min', name='date')
df = data.resample('5min', on='date')['gmv'].sum().reindex(dti, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df['cum_sale'] = df.resample('D', on='date')['gmv'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 Date  gmv  cum_sale
0 2022-11-01 00:00:00    0         0
1 2022-11-01 00:05:00    0         0
2 2022-11-01 00:10:00   10        10
3 2022-11-01 00:15:00    0        10
4 2022-11-01 00:20:00    0        10
5 2022-11-01 00:25:00   20        30
6 2022-11-01 00:30:00    0        30
7 2022-11-01 00:35:00   40        70
```

Comment: You suggested resample method. Does Resample vs Grouper make any difference in this case?

Comment: No you can use both, it doesn't matter. I just prefer use `resample` to have a more concise code.

Comment: Can you look at the edited question please? I am loosing almost all my data when trying to reindex the table.

Comment: Oh I see, it seems you have not only rounded time (0, 5, 10, 15, etc). You have to resample first before reindex and fill missing values. I updated my code, can you check it on your data, please?

Comment: I´ve asked on Pandas´ github about this behavior and they sad that it is a bug.   https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53734#issuecomment-1600005584